# How to get the smallest Integers not yet in a database column

Tags: mysql

I have a table in a MySQL DB with an UNIQUE INT(10) column. The table is pretty populated and the row contains non-consecutive entries of Integer numbers in that column. I would like to do a query, which gets me the smallest number (or the n smallest numbers) that is not in any row.

Example: The table contains rows with values `(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12, 15)` for the column. The sql statement should return i.e. the five lowest non-contained values, which are `4, 6, 9, 11, 13` in this case.

Is this possible with MySQL?

Comment: Disclaimer: I do NOT need this to fill up missing auto increment PK values...

Answer (score 4):

You can use a "numbers" table (it's handy for various operations):

```
CREATE TABLE num
( i UNSIGNED INT NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY (i)
) ;

INSERT INTO num (i)
VALUES
  (1), (2), ..., (1000000) ;
```

Then:

```
SELECT 
    num.i
FROM 
        num
    LEFT JOIN
        tableX AS t
            ON num.i = t.columnX
WHERE 
    t.columnX IS NULL
ORDER BY
    num.i
LIMIT 5
```

or:

```
SELECT 
    num.i
FROM 
    num
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS 
    ( SELECT *
      FROM tableX AS t
      WHERE num.i = t.columnX
    )
ORDER BY
    num.i
LIMIT 5
```

---

Another approach, without using an auxilary table, would be to use MySQL variables. You can test it in [SQL-Fiddle, test-2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/871dc/11). The output is not the same as the previous (just to show that it can be done):

```
SELECT start_id, end_id
FROM 
  ( SELECT 
        IF( t.columnX <> @id, @id, NULL)       AS start_id
      , IF( t.columnX <> @id, t.columnX-1, NULL) AS end_id
      , @rows := @rows + (t.columnX - @id)     AS r
      , @id := t.columnX + 1                   AS running_id
    FROM 
            tableX AS t
        CROSS JOIN  
            ( SELECT @rows := 0
                   , @id := 1
            ) AS dummy
    WHERE
        @rows < 5
    ORDER BY
        t.columnX
    ) AS tmp
WHERE
    start_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I like this idea, but filling and joining the num table would be rather inefficient, if the possible numbers go into the millions (or even billions). Is there a solution without this trick?

Comment: Not if you do it once and you keep that table. A billion rows table would be 4GB (and possibly a bit more with the index). There are recursive ways to achieve the same but MySQL has no CTEs or similar structure.

Comment: A solution with variables would be possible though.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a try and report on performance later.

Answer (score 2):

This will work, but I think it is pretty inefficient. You won't need an extra table though (a table that would be `(2^31-1)*4/1024^3 = 8GB` for all positive numbers in INT). Also I advise you look at why you need this, because it might not be neccesary.

Also it will return the start and end of a range, but not all numbers in that range. (e.g. if you have numbers 1 and 5 it will return {0,2,4,6})

```
SELECT (t.num-1) AS bound FROM t
    WHERE t.num-1 NOT IN (SELECT t.num FROM t)
UNION
SELECT (t.num+1) AS bound FROM t
    WHERE t.num+1 NOT IN (SELECT t.num FROM t)
```

As I said this will be pretty inefficient, JOINs might be faster but you would need benchmark it.

```
SELECT (t.num-1) AS bound FROM t
    LEFT JOIN t AS u ON t.num-1 = u.num
    WHERE u.num IS NULL
UNION
SELECT (t.num+1) AS bound FROM t
    LEFT JOIN t AS u ON t.num+1 = u.num
    WHERE u.num IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll compare this to the other solution performance-wise.